# Show that a given equation has no solutions in integers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Prove that there are no integers $x$ and $y$ such that 
$$x^5-x^4y-13x^3y^2+13x^2y^3+36xy^4-36y^5=77.$$

Firstly setting $x=y$ gives LHS=0. This suggests that $x-y$ is a factor of it, factoring gives 
\begin{align*}
(x-y)(x^4-13x^2y^2+36y^4) &=(x-y)(x^2-9y^2)(x^2-4y^2)\\ &=(x-3y)(x-2y)(x-y)(x+2y)(x+3y)=77.
\end{align*}
Im not sure how to proceed.

Comment: LHS becomes 0 but RHS is still 77,to consider x-y a factor LHS should be equal to RHS

Comment: @THELONEWOLF. Forget about LHS and RHS, when we check for the roots of the polynomial, then we substitute and check when zero comes, right? In this case, putting $x=y$ gave the polynomial as zero, so we concluded that $x-y$ is a root of the polynomial. It had nothing to do with LHS/RHS at all.

Comment: If $x$ and $y$ are integers, then so is $\alpha x-\beta y$ for all integers $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Notice that each of the factors would then by a divisor of $77$. Since $77=7\cdot 11$, each of these factors have to equal either $\pm 1,\pm 7,\pm 11$ or $\pm 77$. This gives you several systems of equations, each of these will contain contradictions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By my comment above, we have that $(x-y)=\pm 1, \pm 7, \pm 11$ or $\pm 77$. Similarly, $(x-2y)=\pm 1, \pm 7, \pm 11$ or $\pm 77$.

Case I: Assume $x-y=1=x-2y$, then $y=0$ and $x=1$, but then $(x-3y)(x-2y)(x-y)(x+2y)(x+3y)=1\neq 77$.

Case II: Assume $x-y=-1$ and $x-2y=1$, then $y=-2$ and $x=-3$, but then $x+3y=-9$ which is not a divisor of $77$.

Case III: Assume $x-y=7$ and $x-2y=1$, then $y=6$ and $x=13$, but then $x+2y=25$ is not a divisor of $77$.

And so on. In principle you can proceed in this fashion and exclude all $64$ cases. You can remove many cases by making some more observations.

You can also work in a reverse way. Notice that $77=1\cdot 77$ or $ 7\cdot 11$. (or $-1\cdot -77$ or $-7\cdot -11$). Thus either one factor is $77$ and all others are $1$. Or one factor is $7$, one other factor is $11$ and all others are $1$ (up to signs). I admit that this seems like a brute force method, but it is doable and will work.